# Why Visual Studio 2019 mark as error some part of a .razor file but the code is compilable?

Tags: blazor

I'm trying some examples of Blazor client-side application like showed on Microsoft web site. I have implemented a ToDoItem class in a file .cs and I use this class in my .razor file.
VS 2019 mark as "could not be found" the reference to the class ToDoItem and AddToDo method in the .razor file, but the code is compilable and the application run correctly.
I have the same problem if I use a reference to the UIMouseEventArgs.
How can I avoid this marks?

````
public class ToDoItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}

``` Razor page code
``` ...
<button onclick="@AddToDo">Add todo</button>

@functions {

    private string newTodo;
    private IList<ToDoItem> todos = new List<ToDoItem>();


    private void AddToDo()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new ToDoItem
            {
                Title = newTodo,
                IsDone = false
            });

            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

[Screnshot of VS2019][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mHtT.png

Sorry found the problem: I need to add the using clausole
@using BlazorFirstApp.Pages
````

Comment: You are running the regular VS2019, and not the Preview, right? Because that is the problem then.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is right. You should be running the version 16.1, it is in preview. Download it [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/).